# matching exact string in Ocaml using regex

Tags: regex, ocaml

How to find a exact match using regular expression in Ocaml? For example, I have a code like this:

```
let contains s1 s2 =
let re = Str.regexp_string s2
in
try ignore (Str.search_forward re s1 0); true
with Not_found -> false
```

where s2 is "_X_1" and s1 feeds strings like "A_1_X_1", "A_1_X_2", ....and so on to the function 'contains'. The aim is to find the exact match when s1 is "A_1_X_1". But the current code finds match even when s1 is "A_1_X_10", "A_1_X_11", "A_1_X_100" etc.

I tried with "[_x_1]", "[_X_1]$" as s2 instead of "_X_1" but does not seem to work. Can somebody suggest what can be wrong?

Comment: You use `Str.regexp_string` which produces a regular expression that matches literally the string passed, without interpreting metacharacters.

Comment: yes you are right Matias. Also contains "A_1_X_1" "_X_1$" returns false

Comment: Yes, I was hoping that the Str.regexp_string will return ^_X_1$ if we pass "_X_1" to it. Hence my code was written in that way. But Str.regexp_string is doing something else...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `$` metacharacter to match the end of the line (which, assuming the string doens't contain multiple lines, is the end of the string). But you can't put that through `Str.regexp_string`; that just escapes the metacharacters. You should first quote the actual substring part, and then append the `$`, and then make a regexp from that:

```
let endswith s1 s2 =
  let re = Str.regexp (Str.quote s2 ^ "$")
  in
  try ignore (Str.search_forward re s1 0); true
  with Not_found -> false
```

Comment: Yes, you are right. I made a mistake by using regexp_string. I should have used regexp. Thank you for the inputs!

Answer (score 2):

`Str.match_end` is what you need:

```
let ends_with patt str =
  let open Str in
  let re = regexp_string patt in
  try
    let len = String.length str in
    ignore (search_backward re str len);
    match_end () == len
  with Not_found -> false
```

With this definition, the function works as you require:

```
# ends_with "_X_1" "A_1_X_10";;
- : bool = false
# ends_with "_X_1" "A_1_X_1";;
- : bool = true
# ends_with "_X_1" "_X_1";;
- : bool = true
# ends_with "_X_1" "";;
- : bool = false
```

Comment: Thank you Matias for your input!

Answer (score 0):

A regex will match anywhere in the input, so the behaviour you see is normal.

You need to anchor your regex: `^_X_1$`.

Also, `[_x_1]` will not help: `[...]` is a character class, here you ask the regex engine to match a character which is `x`, `1` or `_`.

Comment: with ^_X_1$ , it  does not match even _X_1. it returns false for _X_1 as well

Comment: Eh? What regex engine is that?

Comment: Well I am new to Ocaml and do not know much about it. But my initial hunch is the conversion to regex itself is doing something strange. (the Str.regexp_string)

Comment: `Str.regexp_string` is a special function that creates a regex that matches a given string literally. So it specially escapes metacharacters. (The general function to create a regex from a string is `Str.regexp`.)